# ActiveRecord's serialize converts integers to strings? [Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

When I am persisting a hash as a JSON, I expect the hash to be converted to JSON and not modified, but instead the keys are changed from integer to string.

The model:

```
class Shift < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :api_returns, JSON
end
```

Usage:

```
> Shift.create(api_returns: { 123 => '456' })
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "shifts" ("api_returns") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "id"  [["api_returns", "{\"123\":\"456\"}"]]
=> #<Shift:0x007fe785038c60 id: 22, ... api_returns: {"123"=>"456"}>
```

Any ideas how to make ActiveRecord not mangle my input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON can't have integer keys. The keys must be double-quoted strings, no other types are allowed.

http://json.org/

Answer (score 0):

using parseInt(), You can convert them in js,  when you would use them.

```
var a = parseInt("10")
```